# Leaderboard in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Faced the problem that Google documented everything correctly, but it's not in vain, although it goes into the google play account, after which it thinks a little and sends it back to the game.

Perhaps something with the code was wrong.

```c#
private string leaderboard = "CgkI9pfnzM8FEAIQAQ";

void Start()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        if(success) 
        {
            Debug.Log("You have successefully loged in");
        } 
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Login failded");
        }
    });
}

LeaderboardOn()
{
    ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderboard);
}

Hightscore()
{
    if(score>highscore)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", score);
        gameOverHighScoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text ="HIGHSCORE:"+score.ToString();
        Social.ReportScore(score, leaderboard, (bool success) => {
            if (success) print("Successefully added to Leaderboard");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Микита Рєпін 
You activate PlayGamesPlatform by doing:

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

Everything else seems okay, the only problem would be

- `LeaderboardOn()` should be `void LeaderboardOn()`
- `Highstcore()` should be `void Highstcore()`

Comment: This option did not help in solving the problem, can something else advise?